# How to restart a QWizard?

Tags: qt

I have a QWizard that I have subsclassed, that don't want to finish.  When the user clicks the finish button I want to just go back to the beginning.  I first tried just overriding the nextId() method, but that will not allow me to go backwards.  Any other ideas?  This is with Qt 4.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [`restart()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwizard.html#restart) for example, which could be called from `done()`. Note that this resets your fields, though.